# How to develop an architecture for Gitflow

Tags: git, git-flow

i searched alot about using GitFlow but anyone of them didn't help me to solve my problem.
I have a project that will use multiple master branch. That's not like a new release because each release of product can be develop via Gitflow but at the same time they will get core functionalities from latest updates from main master branch. How can i do that with GitFlow. I need something like Seperated Git Flows for each selected branch. And then bind those selected branches to main branch.

I'm thinking i can do that with classic git but i will manage a team so i can't be sure there will not be any mistake at team the gitflow is more easy to teach them but GitFlow's only one master branch approach doesn't fit for my project. I looked up for Enchanced Git Flow approach but it's for multi release too.

[image: Workflow for my Project Model]

Comment: This is a mess and a disaster waiting to happen, and I'm being friendly. Instead of thinking in "multiple master branches", explain the functionality of your product. For example, will you have multiple, different instances of your software deployed at the same time? Or do you have one "core system" which gets modified for each customer? You're probably better off with multiple repositories, submodules and/or a software packaging system (NuGet, Composer, whatever your environment is).

Comment: I have a core project that can be customize. When i have a customer i am creating a new branch for it and then i am customize that branch for customer but at the same time i am continue to develop my master. When i release new master i want to send the new functionalities to old customers without change their customization

Comment: How is what you're describing different than using release branches?

Comment: "multiple master branch" and "main master branch" this sounds confusing - your latest comment sounds like you're using git for dependency management - why isn't the core product one repository - which another client-specific repository imports/is built on?

Comment: @AD7six The new release will merge with previous ones without change customization or their self development

Comment: As @AD7six says, it sounds like the core code should be a library. If client wants new changes in core, easy to update. If client doesn't want the changes, use version pinning. If frequently a client wants only some changes in the core, then probably core library should be split into components (or otherwise reconsider the architecture). Supporting multiple incompatible forks is a guaranteed headache -- it will be bad for you and for your users.

Comment: @AD7six My project can be develop with classic GitFlow but after v1.0 when i setup this to a customer, customer can ask for spesific development. I have to seperate customer's spesific developments while continue to develop main project that will implement to all customers. For Example:  There are 2 customer get an instance at v1.0 then first customer ask for an feature i made this for him but not for 2nd customer. When i release v2.0 for master i have to update both customers project but i have to avoid change first customer's feature.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248209). Before you ask about adjustments to Git-Flow, try to forget about Git for a moment and first identify the way to manage your codebase for multiple customers. In my experience, when a software product contains a large chunk of core product for all customers, and then specific customizations for certain customers, instead of maintaining multiple code bases (or branches as you propose), in the long wrong it ends up being easier to maintain one codebase with customer switches/flags for which functionality to get.

Comment: Another option, similar to what @AD7six proposes, is to have different projects/deployables for each customer with a common codebase (or library for example) that is shared. Note that either way you go, you don't need to maintain separate master branches per customer- which as has been suggested would get extremely messy.

Comment: @TTT thank you for your advices they are very nice i am also think like that but the project will use an opensource project as base so i am trying to do that with this method. I don't have experienced developer in my team so i am trying to solve this problem without change code architecture. But you all guys are right i need to think about project design before gitflow :) Thank you very much to everyone who adviced.